# Is there a way to enlist all of the messages of all the queues in an Azure servicebus and store them in a json?

Tags: c#, json, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I started working with Microsoft Azure fairly recently and wanted to create custom code in c#, so I was able print out the messages for a a single specified queue but i'm having trouble trying to do this for multiple queues and storing this data in a json file

```
static QueueClient queueClient;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sbConnectionString = "connection-string";
    string sbQueueName = "queue-name";

    try
    {
        queueClient = new QueueClient(sbConnectionString, sbQueueName);

        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            AutoComplete = false
        };
        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }
}

static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}

static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you share your current code and explain where are you stuck?

Comment: Yup, ive added code to the point ive gotten to so far

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to enlist all of the messages of all the queues in an Azure servicebus and store them in a json?

If you need multiple queues, using the Service Bus processor is probably not the most convenient way to achieve the goal. Rather, using a `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync()` to get multiple messages would be more efficient. The processor only gets a single message per call. To aggregate messages into a single JSON file would need to be a custom code.

If you don't need to receive messages from the individual queues, I would suggest [auto-forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) from all the queues to a single queue and reading messages in [batches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.receivemessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview) from that single queue. It will help keep your code simpler.